# how to add HorizontalScrollView with toolbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar

I want to add HorizontalScrollView in the toolbar.I try to implement this, but the HorizontalScrollView left and right not aligned correctly.The title also not displayed.I couldn't understand how to add the HorizontalScrollView.Please help me to solve this problem.Any help I really appreciate.

ScreenShot :

[image]

`activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/myAppTool"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:id="@+id/button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Button3"
                android:id="@+id/button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I hope you don't try to implement `tabs` by this way

Comment: @EldarMensutov Bro I want to trigger network details,wifi details,etc .. like a popup window .. . the buttons triggered the popups ..So I used this way ..

Comment: Is there any requirement of Toolbar?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing your code, why you are not using [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) and set `tabMode="scrollable"`?
You can find an example [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout).

Edit, Tabs without `Fragment`
Maybe something like this:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
final TabLayout.Tab tabWiFi = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Button WiFi");
tabLayout.addTab(tabWiFi);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        if (tab == tabWiFi)
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab WiFi Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

      }
});
```

Comment: You are right ..But I am not using the Fragment ..I want to trigger Dialogs using those buttons ..Is this possible with out Fragment?

Comment: @reegan29, it is not usual to use buttons in that location. My suggestion is to show the content you display in dialogs in each tab.

Comment: that's possible you can but your trigger in OnAttach() that's work when you select the fragment see the fragment life cycle http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @Mr.Blue  Thanks for your valuable reply I try to do you are all guys Suggestion ..